# pdf and netbeans

Tags: pdf, netbeans

I am using netbeans to develop my project. I need to put a pdf on a website and according to certain conditions, only parts of the pdf should be view-able.For example, suppose payment made is rs.500. I will let the user view 2 chapters in the pdf for a period of one week. I have no idea how to do this.Can someone help me?

Comment: Netbeans is just an IDE, maybe tell us the language you want to use.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using NetBeans, I'll assume that you're using Java as your language.

You generate PDFs using either XSL-FO or something like [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).  I prefer XSL-FO and Velocity templates, but your situation might be different.

The rules for what to display under different conditions need to be expressed in Java using controllers that accept a request, bind parameters to objects, execute rules, and stream the response as a PDF depending on the outcome.  It's not an easy answer.

Comment: NetBeans is frequently used with PHP or front-end web-languages HTML/CSS/JS, so your assumption _might_ be wrong.

Comment: Might be, but until there's more information it might be correct, too.   If Java turns out to be the language of choice, perhaps you'd consider removing your comment.  I'd wonder how one plans to generate a PDF using HTML/CSS/JS or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There are various Java viewers and several have plugins (there is one at http://www.jpedal.org/support_siNetBeans.php).

Your best bet would be to generate a copy of the PDF with just the pages allowed and then display that.